# Excel formula to search partial match and align row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 column data in Excel like this:

[image]

Can somebody help me write a formula in column C that will take the first name or the last name from column A and match it with column B and paste the values in column C. The following picture will give you the exact idea what I am trying to do. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is not "regular", you can try this formula which uses wild card to look for just the last name.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH("*" &MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99)&"*",$B$1:$B$4,0))
```

It would be simpler if the first part followed some rule, but some have the first initial of the first name at the beginning; and others at the end.

**Edit:** *(explanation added)*

The `FIND` returns the character number of the first `space`
Add 1 to that to get the character number of the next word
Use `MID` to extract that word

Use that word in `MATCH` (with wild-cards before and after), to find it in the array of email addresses.  This will return it's position in the array (row number)

Use that row number as an argument to the `INDEX` function to return the actual email address.

If you want to first examine the email address, you will need to determine which of the letters comprise the last name.  Since this is not regular according to your example, you will need to check both options.

You will not be able to look for the first name from the email, as it is not present.

If you can guarantee that the first part will be follow the rule of one or the other, eg: either

- **FirstInitial**LastName  or
- LastName**FirstInitial**

Then you can try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99)& LEFT(A1,1) &"*",$B$1:$B$4,0)),
INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH( LEFT(A1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99) &"*",$B$1:$B$4,0)))
```

Comment: Great! it worked like a magic! Looking for just the Last name is cool as most of the email id contains Last name. 1) But if I want to look for the First name only, what I need to modify in the formula?, 2) If I wanna reverse i.e. search for 'wyatt' from the mail id 'wyattm@uapb.edu' and align 'Mascot Wyatt' & 3) If I look for the First name from the email id and align full name. What will be those three formulas, can you please answer?

Comment: This is not a code/formula writing site.  I will add to my answer an explanation of how it works.  That should enable you to figure out how to modify it according to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LOWER(MID(A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1),LEN(A1)))&LOWER(MID(A1,1,1))&"*",$B$1:$B$4,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(LOWER(MID(A1,1,1))&LOWER(MID(A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1),LEN(A1)))&"*",$B$1:$B$4,1,FALSE))
```

Its pretty crazy long and would likely be easier to digest and debug broken up into columns instead of one huge formula.

It basically makes FLast and FirstL out of the name field by splitting on the space.

LastF:

```
=LOWER(MID(A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1),LEN(A1)))&LOWER(MID(A1,1,1))
```

And FirstL:

```
=LOWER(MID(A1,1,1))&LOWER(MID(A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1),LEN(A1)))
```

We then make 2 vlookups for these by using wildcards:

LastF:

```
=VLOOKUP([lastfirst equation from above]&"*",$B$1:$B$4,1,FALSE)
```

And FirstL:

```
=VLOOKUP([firstlast equation from above]&"*",$B$1:$B$4,1,FALSE)
```

And then wrap those in IfError so they both get tried:

```
=IfError([firstLast vlookup],[lastfirst vlookup])
```

The rub is that's going to be hell to edit if you ever need to, which is why I suggest doing each piece in another column then referencing the previous one.
You also need to be aware that this answer will get tripped up by essentially the same name - e.g. Sam Smith and Sasha Smith would both match whatever the first entry for ssmith was.  Any solution here will likely have the same pitfall.